# Get-WMIObject include computer name

Tags: powershell, computer-name

I'm trying out a script to go grab installed software on servers remotely. Problem is I want it to output certain attribs including the computer name but I can't seem to figure out how to get the name inserted.

Here is what I have so far...

```
$servers = Get-QADComputer -SearchRoot "OU=servers,OU=mydomain:-),DC=COM" | Select Name
```

...which works fine of course. Then...

```
$servers | % {Get-WMIObject -Class Win32Reg_AddREmovePrograms} | select Displayname,Version,InstallDate,PSComputerName
```

... which provides the full list of software installed on all servers in that OU but the PSComputerName becomes MY COMPUTER (the computer I run the query from - not the computername of the system being queried). The goal is to have the servername the software is installed on on each line item of software. I've asked professor Google and don't seem to see anything helpful (or anything that I understand anyway).

Hope this makes sense. semi-amateur PS script writer so hopefully this is easy for you guys. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Since the object returned from the WMI call doesn't contain the computer you made the request on, you need to include it yourself from include your `ForEach-Object` (`%`) block. You could use `Add-Member` to add it yourself, then do your `Select-Object` outside like you're doing now:

```
$servers | % {
    Get-WMIObject -Class Win32Reg_AddREmovePrograms -ComputerName $_ |
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $_ -PassThru
} | select Displayname,Version,InstallDate,ComputerName
```

Another way is to move the `Select-Object` to inside the block and do it within there, by creating a new property on the fly with a hashtable:

```
$servers | % {
    Get-WMIObject -Class Win32Reg_AddREmovePrograms -computername $_ |
    Select-Object Displayname,Version,InstallDate,@{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32Reg_AddREmovePrograms
```

Does not specify computer to query, so it just query computer command being executed on. Thus `PSComputerName` display `MY COMPUTER`, as `MY COMPUTER` is computer being queried. You have to specify `-ComputerName` parameter to `Get-WMIObject` cmdlet to query specific computer. And `-ComputerName` parameter accept array of computer names, so you can put array of computer names to it instead of using `ForEach-Object` cmdlet and query one computer at time.

Comment: Forgive my newbiness but when you say accept array what would that look like? I looked up the technet on the command and see that "-computername" does not accept a pipeline input so how do I get the array in to the command?

Comment: @CurtChapman Like that `$servers='Server1','Server2','Server3';Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $servers`.

Comment: Ya that seems to give me the output I want. However I really need to develop the $servers variable to contain the properly formatted array so I can query AD for the list. Why doesn't the array work properly when I just query for the servernames in AD?

Comment: @CurtChapman Value for `-ComputerName` parameter should be array of strings. With your code `$servers` is array of custom objects with `Name` property.